# Jquery function does not work after press the space button once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a simple jquery example. I want to sum all numbers that typed by user. The user must press enter after typed the number and if user presses the spacebar the result will be shown on the screen. My problem is, after i pressed the spacebar once no more summation process is executing. I have try the possibles ways that i thought but i could not fix it. Anyone one can help me please ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var typedNumber=0;
var sum = 0;
var textValue = $('#textbox').val();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textbox').keyup(function(event){

            if(event.keyCode == 13){
                textValue = $('#textbox').val();
                typedNumber = parseInt(textValue);
                sum = sum + typedNumber;
                $('#textbox').val("");
            }

            if(event.keyCode == 32 ){
                alert("Summation has been finished!, Sum = "+sum);
                $('#resultMessage').html(sum);
                sum = 0;
                typedNumber = 0;
            }

    });

}); 
</script>
```

Comment: What error are you seeing in the error console?

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/qra8T/

Comment: Seems to work fine -> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/4W2aL/).

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to add the `$('#textbox').val("");` part inside the second if statement too. (Also, as an aside, _declare your variables_ - use a `var` statement to declare `sum` outside the key handler, and use `var` inside the handler to declare your other variables.)

Comment: @Steve There is no error. I think it is a logical problem.No i didn't create .

Comment: It doensn't work after press spacebar once.

Comment: @nnnnnn sorry i have missed some piece of my code.i have edited now.Check it please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll suggest to check if the value in the input field is a number.

```
sum = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textbox').keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            var value = parseInt($('#textbox').val());
            if(!isNaN(value)) {
                sum = sum + value;   
            }
            $('#textbox').val("");
        }
        if(event.keyCode == 32 ){
            alert("Summation has been finished!, Sum = "+sum);
            $('#resultMessage').html(sum);
            $('#textbox').val("");
            sum = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you it works ! But can you explain the difference ? What is change after i check the value is a number. Was it already a number ? Because i am parsing it to an integer.

Comment: `parseInt` doesn't guarantee you that the value will be a number. It could be a `NaN` which is `not a number` ;) So, you are adding a no-number variable to the `sum`. It happens because in some cases you pass an interval to `parseInt`.

Comment: How the parseInt couldn't guarantee that ? and what happens if i assume that i am going to type only numbers to the textbox ? Why i have to check it again ? Sorry for my questions i just want to understand it correctly :)

Comment: `parseInt` tries to convert the given variable to a number. If you pass a letter you will get `NaN` as a result. So, that's something that you can't add to your `sum` variable. As a result `sum` also gets `NaN`. That's why before to make `sum = sum + value` you need to check if `value` is an actual number.

Answer (score 1):

You must first define the `sum` variable before you use it. Also, you should use preventDefault within the keyup handler

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/9Q3dJ/

Comment: i have missed some piece of my code,now i have edited.Check this version please.It is not working in this way also.